# How can I space two items in a row using flexbox CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to the flexbox CSS system, so forgive my lack of knowledge.
But in fact, there you have it, I managed to fix a problem that was none other than implementing a "`max-width: 100%;`" in the **2nd section** which *overflowed* when we were on a screen of less than *600* pixels.

Now my first section looks weird, the SVG is shrunk, and everything is placed in the absolute center.

[image]

Here is how it is supposed to look like:
[image]

And finally, here is my code:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arvo:wght@400;700&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --body-bg:#fff;
  --body-text:#000000;
  --theme_hero:linear-gradient(45deg, #FF6666, #FF9C75);
  --theme_hero_text:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  --theme_hero_subtitle:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  --theme_hero_text_desc: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  --theme_borders:rgba(190, 196, 211, 0.507);
  --theme_link:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  --theme_link-hover:rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.5);
  --theme_footer:#f6fcff;
  --box:#f4f4f4;
  /*! grid */
  --grid-p:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  --shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  --content-theme:"";
}

._container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

._row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
._row ._col {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.n-hero {
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background: var(--theme_hero);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 96%);
}
.n-hero .n-hero__title {
  font-family: "Arvo", serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: var(--theme_hero_text);
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1em;
  animation: n-hero__title 1s ease forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.n-hero .n-hero__subtitle {
  font-family: "Arvo", serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: var(--theme_hero_subtitle);
  max-width: 20em;
  font-weight: 400;
  animation: n-hero__subtitle 1s ease 0.3s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.n-hero .n-hero__desc {
  color: var(--theme_hero_text_desc);
  font-size: 11pt;
  max-width: 28em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@keyframes n-hero__title {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes n-hero__subtitle {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.n-hero {
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background: var(--theme_hero);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 96%);
}
.n-hero .n-hero__title {
  font-family: "Arvo", serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: var(--theme_hero_text);
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1em;
  animation: n-hero__title 1s ease forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.n-hero .n-hero__subtitle {
  font-family: "Arvo", serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: var(--theme_hero_subtitle);
  max-width: 20em;
  font-weight: 400;
  animation: n-hero__subtitle 1s ease 0.3s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.n-hero .n-hero__desc {
  color: var(--theme_hero_text_desc);
  font-size: 11pt;
  max-width: 28em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@keyframes n-hero__title {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes n-hero__subtitle {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.n-hero__banner {
  background-image: url("https://beta.nosfera.app/statics/_i/hero__banner.svg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 1024px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: n-hero__banner 1s ease 0.5s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes n-hero__banner {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(-2deg) scale(1.1) translateX(100px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(3deg) scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1deg) scale(1) translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="n-hero  ">

        <div class="_container  ">
            <div class="_row    ">

                <div class="_col    ">
                    <h1 class="n-hero__title    ">Nosfera</h1>
                    <h6 class="n-hero__subtitle     ">Social network to connect with other artists around the world.</h6>
                    <!-- <p class="n-hero__desc  _spacing    ">Nosfera is a social network allowing any artist to connect with anyone
                        using sharing and compassion.</p>
                        <p class="n-hero__desc  ">Upload your works of art and let people give their opinions, collect as many likes and shares as possible!</p> -->
                </div>
    
                <div class=" _col    ">
                    <div class="n-hero__banner  "></div>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's is the source of the problem:

```
._container {
    max-width: 1280px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;   <------ PROBLEM
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
```

By setting horizontal auto margins, you are forcing the flex items to be centered ([full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)).

Also, `._container` is a flex item, but it's set to `auto` width by default, meaning it will be the length of the content. Add `flex: 1` to give it the full width of its parent container.

Adjust the height of the image in `.n-hero__banner`. It's set at 1024px, so it will overflow on smaller screens. Consider a dynamic height value, such as `%` or `vh`.

Comment: Tried your code and it worked well until I noticed my content wasn't centered anymore, how can I manage to make it centered again? `justify-content:center` won't work.

Comment: Can you post a codepen or jsfiddle here with what you have? It worked for me when I tested it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jesztar/pen/wvovebY here you go !

Comment: Add `justify-content: center` to `.n-hero`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the ._container in css and add `width: 100%;` or `flex: 1;` (credits to @MichaelBenjamin) .Add also some padding in order to be more beautiful

```
._container {
    max-width: 1280px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arvo:wght@400;700&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --body-bg:#fff;
  --body-text:#000000;
  --theme_hero:linear-gradient(45deg, #FF6666, #FF9C75);
  --theme_hero_text:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  --theme_hero_subtitle:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  --theme_hero_text_desc: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  --theme_borders:rgba(190, 196, 211, 0.507);
  --theme_link:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  --theme_link-hover:rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.5);
  --theme_footer:#f6fcff;
  --box:#f4f4f4;
  /*! grid */
  --grid-p:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  --shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  --content-theme:"";
}

._container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

._row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
._row ._col {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.n-hero {
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background: var(--theme_hero);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 96%);
}
.n-hero .n-hero__title {
  font-family: "Arvo", serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: var(--theme_hero_text);
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1em;
  animation: n-hero__title 1s ease forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.n-hero .n-hero__subtitle {
  font-family: "Arvo", serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: var(--theme_hero_subtitle);
  max-width: 20em;
  font-weight: 400;
  animation: n-hero__subtitle 1s ease 0.3s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.n-hero .n-hero__desc {
  color: var(--theme_hero_text_desc);
  font-size: 11pt;
  max-width: 28em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@keyframes n-hero__title {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes n-hero__subtitle {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.n-hero {
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background: var(--theme_hero);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 96%);
}
.n-hero .n-hero__title {
  font-family: "Arvo", serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: var(--theme_hero_text);
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1em;
  animation: n-hero__title 1s ease forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.n-hero .n-hero__subtitle {
  font-family: "Arvo", serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: var(--theme_hero_subtitle);
  max-width: 20em;
  font-weight: 400;
  animation: n-hero__subtitle 1s ease 0.3s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.n-hero .n-hero__desc {
  color: var(--theme_hero_text_desc);
  font-size: 11pt;
  max-width: 28em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@keyframes n-hero__title {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes n-hero__subtitle {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.n-hero__banner {
  background-image: url("https://beta.nosfera.app/statics/_i/hero__banner.svg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 1024px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: n-hero__banner 1s ease 0.5s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes n-hero__banner {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(-2deg) scale(1.1) translateX(100px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(3deg) scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1deg) scale(1) translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="n-hero  ">

        <div class="_container  ">
            <div class="_row    ">

                <div class="_col    ">
                    <h1 class="n-hero__title    ">Nosfera</h1>
                    <h6 class="n-hero__subtitle     ">Social network to connect with other artists around the world.</h6>
                    <!-- <p class="n-hero__desc  _spacing    ">Nosfera is a social network allowing any artist to connect with anyone
                        using sharing and compassion.</p>
                        <p class="n-hero__desc  ">Upload your works of art and let people give their opinions, collect as many likes and shares as possible!</p> -->
                </div>
    
                <div class=" _col    ">
                    <div class="n-hero__banner  "></div>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```